# How to use MavenBuildHelper in Maven mojo

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

I am developing a maven-plugin with multiple Mojos. In one of them, my goal is to attach additional artifact to my project. Similar to [attach-artifact of maven-build-helper-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html). But I don't want to use any given build plugin, I want to do it through my Mojo.

I know that I have to use [MavenProjectHelper.attachArtifact](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.html#attachArtifact(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)). Because MavenProject.attachArtifact is deprecated.

What I have now is this (in the mojo.java):

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;

@Parameter(defaultValue = "${helper}", required = true, readonly = true)
protected MavenProjectHelper projectHelper;
```

And in `execute` method:

```
projectHelper.attachArtifact(project, "plugin", file);
```

But the problem is, `MavenProjectHelper`'s default value is not `${helper}`. Which is why, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal com.company.product.repo:my-plugin:1.0.1:attach-artifact (default) on project consumer-plugin: The parameters 'projectHelper' for goal com.company.product.repo:my-plugin:1.0.1:attach-artifact are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

How do I give it the correct value? Like `MavenSession`'s `${session}`, I have assumed that `MavenProjectHelper` has a default value. If so, what is it? If not, then how can I give the correct value to `MavenProjectHelper` parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`MavenProjectHelper`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.html) is a Plexus component, not a plugin parameter, and should be injected by annotating it with the [`@org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Component.html) annotation:

> Used to configure injection of Plexus components by `MavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(...)`.

Thus, you should have instead:

```
@Component
private MavenProjectHelper projectHelper;
```

This annotation, just like `@Parameter`, comes with the [Plugin Tools](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/maven-plugin-annotations/) for annotations, that you can declare in the POM of your Maven plugin with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

To clarify further, what you can inject with [`@Parameter`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.html) is documented in the Javadoc of the [`PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html) class (among others, `session` for the Maven session, `project` for the current Maven project or `mojoExecution` for the current Mojo execution).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. If I had to give the value of `role` manually, what would it be and where can I find it? For example, in `MavenResourcesFiltering`, I am using `role = org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesFiltering.class`

Comment: @ChurchillNolan The role defaults to the class of the annotated type. It would be needed, for example, if you want to inject something into a field whose type isn't the class of the component. Example: `Archiver` has multiple implementations, like `JarArchiver`. If you specifically want a `JarArchiver`, not any other, then your field would be of type `JarArchiver`, so you'll need to tell that the role is `Archiver.class` (since a `JarArchiver` is a component of role `Archiver`). Typically, you would use with `hint`, since you need to distinguish what kind of things you want to have injected.